# How to get size of two arrays?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My question is, how do I get the size of both arrays?
I've tried so many things, can't get any of them to work

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc36ebac1f4d52582abc3d1"),
    "array1" : [ 
        {
            "array2" : [ 
                "This is a test!", 
                "test1"
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

the `array1` and `array2` inside the object, that's also inside `array1`

so, `array1` is of size 1,
`array2` is of size2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For array1 size, you can unwind array1 then use count or length.

```
db.getCollection("stackans").aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$array1"
  }
],function(err ,data){
    console.log(data.length)
});
```

Comment: this returns multiple documents as much elements present in the array1.